# How to detect if button1 was pressed in a If statement. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so when the button is pressed, it disables the button and allows you to select the mouse coordinates. (With right click) then enable back the button. How do you detect if button1 was pressed for the if statement while keeping the timer?

```
    If Button1.clicked Then
```

This is where I need the If statement to detect button1 being pressed.

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If Button1.clicked Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
        If GetAsyncKeyState(2) Then
            TextBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X
            TextBox2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use a CheckBox instead of a button so you can check the `Checked` property.  A button might still be used to start/stop the timer

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, just create a form level variable called "pressed" and set it to true on the button's MouseDown event, and false in the MouseUp event.

Comment: @LarsTech Yea - that was for the OP's benefit, of course

Comment: You could start your timer when the button is pressed. I'm having a hard time understanding the use of your timer and I'm thinking your problem could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks with the help of @the_lotus I found a way around the timer/button issue.
Instead of looking for the button press within the timer statement, you control if the timer is on or off.

Lotus also asked for the reasoning behind the timer. The timer is so the form always looks for a input, not just when the button is pressed.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Timer2.Interval = 5
    Timer2.Enabled = True
    Me.Button1.Text = "Set Posistion 1"
End Sub

Sub Timer2_Tick() Handles Timer2.Tick
    If GetAsyncKeyState(2) Then
        TextBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X
        TextBox2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        Me.Button1.Text = "Reset Position"
    End If
End Sub
```